# Wifi disconnects when a new network adapter is activated

Tags: networking

I have installed debian on a raspberry pi using berryboot. Berryboot is setup to copy wpa_supplicant config to main OS and enable wpa_supplicant on boot when the OS is first installed to my knowledge. The problem is I tried installing Hamachi and when the Hamachi service starts up at boot the wifi gets disconnected. Disabling wifi and enabling it does not fix the problem. I had a look at the routing table it's blank after Hamachi starts up. I uninstalled Hamachi now the wifi is working fine again. I tried connecting to a pptpd server using pptp-client however I had the same problem when I go to connect using eg. (pon tunnel1) the wifi drops out routing table is cleared and left blank. I don't understand what is wrong is this a common problem? Are there any log files that could give me some clues on what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem with Hamachi. I had a similar issue with Windows and I personally gave up on it. Had to uninstall it as I only needed it for 1 game. Heres some answers which may help

Log file is located: 
 `/var/lib/logmein-hamachi/h2-engine.log`

And you could try this fix that works on Ubuntu:

Creating a config file in hamachi directory (where the other files client.pub, client.pri, etc. are located) and just writing:

```
KeepAlive 100
```

Then restarting Hamachi and it should all work.

REF :[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10801/why-hamachi-time-outs-after-5-minutes-or-so)